# WPF: Hidden parent and visible child

Tags: wpf

As of last night, I decided to start learning about WPF and have been reading through a number of online tutorials and books.  This is a huge shift.

One feature that has fascinated me is the implicit property value inheritance.  I know in the WinForms world, if a control is not visible then neither are any of the child controls.  Same seems to be true in the WPF world, as expected.  I wondered if explicitly setting the child control's Visibility property would allow for an invisible parent and visible child and it did not.

Is this something that would be possible in WPF?  Can you have a container control that is hidden with visible children?  This is more an exercise of curiosity than anything.  I'm still trying to wrap my head around a lot of what I've been reading.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible to have a visible child inside an invisible parent.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? I can set the visibility to visible of a child control while a parent remains hidden. Does that change the child's state (i.e. once I make the parent visible, is the child automatically visible or is the child's visibility change a no-op)?

Comment: @Ternary: The `Visibilty` property will be persisted, but you won't actually see anything until the parent is made visible.

Comment: What about a Popup in a collapsed parent Grid for instance ?